# Is there a way to self assign a rounded float to a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, rounding

I want to turn `var = var.round(2)` into something, like `var = var + 1` turns into `var += 1`.

Is there a way to do that in Ruby?

I already tried `round!` method but it does not work like `gsub!` and other methods.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that.

```
class Float
  def ^(arg)
    round(arg)
  end
end
```

Let's try it.

```
x = 2.12345
```

```
x ^ 2   #=> 2.12
x       #=> 2.12345, x is unchanged
x ^= 2  #=> 2.12
x       #=> 2.12, x is assigned the value 2.12
```

This should not cause a problem as `Float.instance_methods.include?(:^) #=> false`, though that could change in future.

`+=`, `*=`, `-=` and so on are called [self assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#operator)  expressions or, more commonly, [assignment operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm). `x += 2` assigns the same value to `x` as does `x = x + 2`. Notice that if `x` is the argument of a method that contains this expression `x` is not mutated in the calling method.

The operator expression preceding the equals sign is permitted to be any one of the following, and nothing else:

```
+  -  *  /  %  **  &  |  ^  <<  >>  &&  ||
```

Of these, the following are `Float` instance methods

```
**  %  *  +  -  /
```

Using one of these would obviously be ill-advised.

The operators `&&` and `||` are not implemented as methods so they cannot be used. That leaves the following symbols or pairs of symbols that could be safely used in place of my method `^` above, at least for current (and I believe older) versions of Ruby.

```
&  |  ^  <<  >>
```

I trust the question is academic, prompted by curiosity alone.

Comment: Oh the horror. I would at least pick an "operational"  method `Float` doesn't implement like `^`.

Comment: @engineersmnky, very good point. I've edited my answer accordingly. Readers: originally I overwrote Float's existing `+` method, causing no end of troubles. Changing the method name to one that is not the name of a Float instance method (such as `^`) avoids that problem.

Comment: Well I can't upvote again but I approve of this edit far more than the original defiling of `Float#+` and I cannot think of a logical implementation for `Float#^` since "to the power of" is already implemented via `**`

Comment: Glad you added "i trust ..." to that answer.
I learned something new today.... but what hate to see it in a codebase that I need to touch.

Comment: I think it should be noted that ```^``` is actually used in the ```Numeric``` class as a bitwise XOR operator.  Although I doubt built-in implementation would happen anytime soon if ever, I think there could/would definitely be some value in the ability to perform ```exclusive or``` operations within the ```Float``` class.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelB. Don't you mean `^` is defined for `Integer` and not `Numeric` (`Numeric.instance_methods.include?(:^) #=> false`)? It's still a problem for floats represented as integers though. In fact, whereas no `Numeric` or `Float` instance method is named `:&`, `:|`, `:^`, `:<<` or `:>>`, there is an `Integer` instance method for all five of those names! That's not so terrible, however, as the question is, no doubt, purely academic.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I actually realized my mistake afterward and thought to go back and change ```Numeric``` to ```Integer``` but I passed the 5 minute window and didn't want to retype the whole thing on my phone.  Funny because I knew you would notice and correct it too, so I wasn't worried about it : )

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds to me like you're trying to do is modify or mutate the variable *in place* or *destructively*.  Some methods are destructive right out of the box, and others like `gsub`/`gsub!` have both a destructive and non-destructive version.

The problem here is that Ruby doesn't have any destructive methods for anything in the `Numeric` class like they do for the `String`, `Array`, and `Hash` classes.  So, to answer your question...No, I don't think there's any great way to do that in Ruby that doesn't involve some ill-advised under the hood manipulation.

Answer (score -2):

No, it's impossible because objects of some Ruby classes are immutable.

Ruby provides a method `#object_id` that returns an object id inside Ruby Virtual Machine. Or you can use the method `equal?` that tells whether two objects are actually the same objects in memory.

Hashes, Strings, and Array are mutable, whereas Symbol, Float, and Integer are immutable.

If you go to irb you can see something like that:

```bash
irb(main):009:0> 345.object_id
=> 691
irb(main):010:0> 345.object_id
=> 691
irb(main):011:0> 345.6.equal?(345.6)
=> true
irb(main):012:0> {}.equal?({})
=> false
irb(main):013:0> {}.object_id
=> 100360
irb(main):014:0> {}.object_id
=> 111840
```

So, there is no way to change an immutable object held by a variable.
The only way is to make the variable point to another object.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to mutate the float. They ask for a shortcut to assign a rounded value to the same variable.